# Homophone fills the blanks

Tags: wordplay

A homophone fills all the blanks in the following sentence

> While visiting India, Mr. ____ ____, a ____ chap, watched locals enjoying ____, ___ .

The homophone constitutes 4 separate words (one split) in the above sentence.

Have a go at it!

Comment: So one homophone will come up twice?

Comment: @Duck - I think when OP says "one split", one of the homophones will actually be two words and fill two of the blanks.

Comment: Oh, that makes way more sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this

> While visiting India, Mr. **Ho** **Li**, a **holy** chap, watched locals enjoying **Holi**, **wholly** .

Comment: Boy your knowledge of english is amazing @hexomino

Comment: Nice, but Holi, wholly, is a little bit of a stretch. +1 :)

Comment: Holy moley, what a nice answer!